# Find Angle $TXU$

Tags: angle

[image]

> Find Angle TXU.

I have tried to consider the kite MTXU, as well as tried to apply some circle angle laws, but have not been able to get angle TXU.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $\angle TMU=2\angle TSU$ (a central angle is twice the inscribed angle) and $\angle TXU=180^{\circ}-\angle TSU$ (opposite angles in a circle sum to $180^{\circ}$).

Comment: Why so? Could you please include your reasoning?

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

**strong text***emphasized text*

1. List item

REFLEX ∠TMU= 2∠TXU (a central angle is twice the inscribed angle)

∠TMU =  ∠RMS = 50 (VERTICALLY OPPOSITE ANGLES)

REFLEX ∠TMU = 360 - 
 ∠TMU = 310

∠TXU =1/2 REFLEX ∠TMU
      = 1/2 * 310
       =155